# Creat alpha/beta release without defined group but not visible on Play Store?

Tags: android

I have a small app which I want to use for private purposes. I want to distribute it to a certain group of people, without the app being visible on Play Store.

I provided the link to the Alpha Channel, without adding any accounts, but they cannot sign in.

How do I do that? I want them to become tester just by clicking on the link, I don't want to add their accounts and I don't want the app to be visible on Play Store

Answer (score 0):

Better try out [Fabric](https://fabric.io/). I use fabric for distribution of debug build to client and testers. Its a private platform for distribution, so won't be visible in PlayStore. Better, it also has a crash reporting tool which is now integrated with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

As per Play store they dont allow that, u need to add accounts in order to let them test via alpha link